# Live character movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First I am sorry to ask a silly question like that but I am not getting any answer anywhere and I am new in a.s.3.

I want my character move so I have 3 animation mc frame. 1 standby mode 2 walk forward 3 walk left. So I did the coding its working perfectly except its not moving (I mean its not changing its place which is 7 per frame)

Here is my code

```
stop();

var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

kims.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveKim);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, UnsetKeyPressed);

function moveKim(event:Event){

    if (leftPressed)
    {
        kims.x -= 7;
    } 

    if (rightPressed)
    {
        kims.x += 7;    
    }       
}

function SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            gotoAndStop(3);

            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            gotoAndStop(2);

            break;
        }
    }
}

function UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            gotoAndStop(1);

            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;

            gotoAndStop(1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `enterFrame` event is not triggered in your code. `GotoAndStop(3)` means that your movieClip goto frame 3 and then stop play.

And you put one animation in one frame? is it just a picture? You can use a movieClip as walk animation. The code is as follow:

```
function moveKim(event:Event){

if (leftPressed)
{
    kims.x -= 7;
} 

if (rightPressed)
{
    kims.x += 7;    
}
```

}

function SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

```
switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.LEFT:
    {
        leftPressed = true;
        _animate.setAnimation("walk");// change the animation from stand to walk;
        _animate.gotoAndPlay(1);


        break;
    }

}
```

}

And if you also can use a timer to control your animation.
You can learn this in Chapter 24 of Essential ActionScript 3.0.